# Bash: if statement vs && when checking return codes

Tags: bash

I've seen checks for return codes typically with an `if` statement:

```
if [ "${rc}" -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "error"
   exit 1
fi
```

I've also infrequently seen checks that utilize `&&` to do the same:

```
[ "${rc}" -ne 0 ] && echo "error" && exit 1
```

Is there a difference between the two other than readability? Does one have benefits over the other?

Comment: [BashPitfalls #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3) is closely related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two are not equivalent, though with `echo` the risk is minimal. In the first, `exit 1` will execute whether or not `echo` succeeds. In the second, the `echo` must succeed for `exit 1` to execute. The `if` statement would more accurately be "translated" as

```
[ "$rc" -ne 0 ] && { echo "error"; exit 1; }
```

---

If you want to use `&&` *and* have readable code, define a function to produce an error message and exit:

```
abort () {
  echo "$1" >&2  # error messages go to standard error!
  exit 1
}

[ "$rc" -ne 0 ] && abort "error"
```